# Official Softlayer script to retrieve locations ids does not work

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I used to use the following script for retrieving the different locations ids, to create an VSI order:

https://softlayer.github.io/python/list_packages/

Specifically:

```
def getAllLocations(self):
    mask = "mask[id,locations[id,name]]"
    result = self.client['SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing'].getAllObjects(mask=mask);
    pp(result)
```

Unfortunately meanwhile it throws the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 59, in <module>
    main.getAllLocations()
  File "new.py", line 52, in getAllLocations
    result = self.client['SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing'].getAllObjects(mask=mask);
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 392, in call_handler
    return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 360, in call
    return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 263, in call
    return self.transport(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 195, in __call__
   raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SOAP-ENV:Server): Internal Error
```

Is there something that needs to be changed within the function?

Answer (score 0):

Nope your code is fine the problem is that this is an issue with the method which is not working I am gonna report the issue or if you want it you can open an softlayer's ticket and report the issue yourself.

Answer (score 0):

An issue with the getAllObjects method was fixed yesterday for this service. Please try the request again.